# Detect and show unicode charactors inside a String in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Can anybody help me to solve this problem.
I have a string which containes unicode like german umlaut for example i have a String like this

```
String text = "kapazitu00e4tsorientierte";
```

how can i show this string in flutter Text Widget with the unicode inside it?

Comment: If this is what you get from the backend, then you need to tell your backend to fix their bugs. I strongly suspect you get something else though. Can you show us the *exact* message you get from your backend?

Comment: yes i get this response {
        "name": "li",
        "content": [
          "Variable Arbeitszeit, Arbeit auf Abruf, KAPOVAZ = kapazitu00e4tsorientierte, variable Arbeitszeit, nach u00a7 12 Gesetz u00fcber Teilzeitarbeit und befristete Arbeitsvertru00e4ge, Fragen der innerbetrieblichen Ausgestaltung,"
        ]
      },

Comment: That is just broken. It either broke on your side or theirs, but transporting UNICODE text from their API to you should be no problem. Can you post a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

you cando like this.

```
Center(
        child: Container(
          child:    Text('2018 \u00a9 Authors Name')
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: yes but i cant have control over the text. I get the text from backend in this form "kapazitu00e4tsorientierte"